# I set up a private ssh key, but VSCode constantly asks for a password when connecting using the key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I use SSH connections to my server in VSCode, and I added a private key so that I won't be prompted for a password when connecting via SSH.
However, when I try to connect to the server through Visual Studio Code, VSCode keeps asking for a password.

The private key itself was generated using the PuttyGen program, and then converted to OpenSSH.
Can you help me solve my problem.

Comment: what if you just submit an empty string when prompted? Isn't that the default password if you don't specify one?

Comment: are you gong to delete and ask the same question each hour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77270520/i-set-up-a-private-ssh-key-but-vscode-constantly-asks-for-a-password-when-conne

Comment: When sending an empty string an error occurs.